# Change a Href Link with JavaScript Wordpress Website. Where can i edit Javascript?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, href

I have a Wordpress site and created it with Elementor. Now I would like to change a button link on a subpage that cannot be edited with Elementor. When you click the button, I want you to come to a different page than the default page.

I can probably change this with JavaScript, i.e. the link structure / shortcode of the link. But I don't know where to write it down or edit it? This is not possible with the customizer. And what does the code have to look like? I am not familiar with Javascript.

A Example:

Default Button-Link (**checkout-Shortcode**):

```
<a href="https://examplesite.com/checkout/" class="fb_btn_fill ">Auschecken</a>
```

And i want to change it to (**checkout2-Shortcode**):

```
<a href="https://examplesite.com/checkout2/" class="fb_btn_fill ">Auschecken</a>
```

Please Help!

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve] of what you tried

Comment: I'm looking for the same solution

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own js files in: **"Appearance > Custom Layouts > Add New"**

Name the file like `custom-script.js` and it will be js

You write your code how you want and below you have the part **"Custom Layout Settings"**, you can choose the pages where you want to display it and others options.